# How can I watch LDAP traffic on port 389?

Tags: debugging, proxy, ldap, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I use Charles Web Debugging Proxy to watch traffic on ports 80 / 443 for HTTP and HTTPS requests. With Mac OS X, what program can I use to watch traffic on port 389 / 636 for `ldap://` and `ldaps://`? I'm interested in seeing the actual requests / responses, partially to see how secure they are and what the differences are, and  partially just because I'm curious as to what the requests look like.

Comment: Please refer : https://iamtechtips.com/capture-ldap-queries-wireshark/
It has got detailed step by step instruction on capturing and analyzing LDAP traffic with wireshark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted, Wireshark or tcpdump. You will not be able to judge the security of the requests and responses, because you must view the unsecured connection traffic. If it were encrypted, you would not be available to view the traffic unencrypted. SSL or StartTLS (as an extended operation) should be used to secure LDAP traffic. For more information about the LDAP message envelope, see [RFC4511](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mac OS X's built in `tcpdump` command, I believe you want a call similar to `sudo tcpdump -i en0 port 389,636`, though there are other flags on the man page to print out the actual request data (try `man tcpdump`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

Answer (score -1):

`tcpdump -n not port ssh and  port 389 and not broadcast and not multicast`